# How to make Mercurial detect changes made to the target of a symlink

Tags: version-control, mercurial, symlink, symlink-traversal

I have a project version-controlled by the Mercurial (project `main`). The project references (uses) some files from another project (`sub`) by a symbolic link in the `main` pointing to a file in `sub`. The symbolic link is added to the `main`'s repository.

The problem is that Mercurial doesn't detect changes made to the target file at `sub`, not marking the symlink as 'M' (modified).

The situation is shown in the following example:

Create, init and commit initial repos:

```
$ mkdir crap
$ cd crap
$ mkdir main sub
$ cd sub
$ nano sub.txt
$ hg init
$ hg add sub.txt 
$ cd ../main/
$ nano main.txt
$ ln -s ../sub/sub.txt ./sub.txt
$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 ruslan ruslan 4096 Jan 15 12:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 ruslan ruslan 4096 Jan 15 12:48 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ruslan ruslan   20 Jan 15 12:51 main.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ruslan ruslan   14 Jan 15 12:51 sub.txt -> ../sub/sub.txt
$ hg init
$ hg add main.txt sub.txt 
$ hg commit -m "First"
$ cd ../sub
$ hg commit -m "Sub First"
$ hg status ./sub -A
C sub/sub.txt
$ hg status ./main -A
C main/main.txt
C main/sub.txt
```

now modify and commit the target in `sub`:

```
$ nano ./sub/sub.txt 
$ hg status ./sub -A
M sub/sub.txt
$ hg commit ./sub -m "Modified"
$ hg status ./sub -A
C sub/sub.txt
```

now status of the `main` shows that the symlink that references the target is not marked as 'M':

```
$ hg status ./main -A
C main/main.txt
C main/sub.txt
```

modifying the `sub` again without the commit shows 'M' in `sub` but not in `main`:

```
$ nano ./sub/sub.txt 
$ hg status ./sub
M sub/sub.txt
$ hg status ./main -A
C main/main.txt
C main/sub.txt
```

How can I properly make Mercurial detect changes in symlinks' targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. For [security reasons](http://markmail.org/message/3lhiwfwhdqcjirop), Mercurial never traverses symbolic links.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to cross-reference repositories then?

Comment: One thing you could do is have sub as a subrepo of main.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hard link instead by omitting `-s` parameter when creating with `ln`.

I recommend appending `.hardlink` to be explicit and modifying your `ls` to [highlight hardlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/12972/how-can-you-see-the-actual-hard-link-by-ls).

On a windows machine I have used same approach using 
[Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) utility; I donated to the author and you should do the same :).

[image]